# PHP mssql and while loop skips one item

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a little issue, Im trying to echo all items from database, that meet my conditions. There are 4 items - but I get printed only 3 of them. Any idea?

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT Description
        FROM MI_Tracker
        WHERE Status ='In Progress'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
do  
{ echo $row['Description'],'<br>';}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) );
```

**CODE EDIT:**

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {

}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT Description
        FROM MI_Tracker
        WHERE Status ='In Progress'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
{ echo $row['Description'],'<br>';}
```

Still - 1 item is missing.

Comment: Does the missing item has Status 'In Progress' as the query filters?

Comment: Yes it is completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first occurrence of the following line from your code:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And also the other fetch you have:

```
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This was the killer: it made you lose one of the rows, as you just moved the pointer to the third row with this `if`.
Instead, check for errors on the *$stmt* variable directly, and use a standard while loop, like this:

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['Description'],'<br>';
}
```

It fetches a row, but since you have a `while` loop doing that later on, you never process that first row. The loop executes the fetch again before you are doing anything with it, meaning you lost the first row.

Comment: My mistake, there was 2 items missing, now only one missing. Still - not good enough

Comment: Ah! Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Just do this while

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) );
```

Without the declaration before of this if:

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); //Remove this
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
```

Check example here.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit. Change if for if( $stmt === false) {